# Drawing several circles in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw several circles in Google Maps API v3. I have found a script which seems to do right what I want. But so far, it works only for one circle. How should this code look like to draw "birrfeld" AND "zuerich"?

```
<script>
var birrfeld=new google.maps.LatLng(47.443411,8.234478);
var aelggialp=new google.maps.LatLng(46.80121,8.226692);
var zuerich=new google.maps.LatLng(47.463031,8.549252);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
center:aelggialp,
zoom:8,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
center:birrfeld,
radius:6000,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
strokeOpacity:0.8,
strokeWeight:2,
fillColor:"#0000FF",
fillOpacity:0.4
});
var zuerich = new google.maps.Circle({
center:zuerich,
radius:8000,
strokeColor:"#0000FF",
strokeOpacity:0.8,
strokeWeight:2,
fillColor:"#0000FF",
fillOpacity:0.4
});

myCity.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: If the below answer is not correct any longer, what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling:

```
zuerich.setMap(map);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jKuck/